# iOS tcp socket json from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, tcp

In my app i am opening a TCP socket connection to my server and am then waiting for data. My server sends all the data in JSON and a message sent from the server can look like this:

> {\"type\":\"message\", \"msg\": \"\", \"visitorNick\":
>   \"nickName\", \"customField1\": \"\", \"visitorNick\": \"Visitor " +
>   obj.channel + "\", \"time\": \"" + getDateTime() + "\", \"channel\":
>   \"" + obj.channel + "\"}\n

In my app i am reading by using a runloop:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {


    switch (streamEvent) {

        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Stream opened");

            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:



            if (theStream == inputStream) {


                uint8_t buffer[1024];
                int len;
                NSMutableData *output = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
                while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if (len > 0) {
                        [output appendBytes: (const void *)buffer length:len];
                    }
                }

                NSString *outputData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:output encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                outputData = [outputData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
                outputData = [outputData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"} {"
                                                     withString:@"} , {"];



                NSLog(@"RECIEVED ----------------------> %@", outputData);

                // Parse the message and add it to the right method
                NSError* error;
                NSDictionary *JSON =
                [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [outputData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                  error: &error];


                NSString* type = [JSON objectForKey:@"type"];

                if(error) {
                    NSLog(@"PARSE ERROR ------------->>>>> : %@\n", error);
                }

                NSLog(@"SERVER TYPE --> %@\n", type);

                if([type isEqualToString:@"message"]) {
                    //NSLog(@"New chat message: %@", output);

                    [self messageReceived:outputData];

                }

            }
            break;


        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:

            NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
            isConnected = 0;

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showReconnect" object:nil];
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.06];
            [self initNetworkCommunication];

            break;

        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:

            [theStream close];
            [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            NSLog(@"STREAM PAUSED");
            theStream = nil;

            break;

    }
}
```

I want the `\n` to force the app to read one JSON at a time (In java for example the `\n` works as a flush, so that one message is read at a time). Right now the app is sometimes reading multiple JSONS at a time.

I think that the problem lies here:

```
            uint8_t buffer[1024];
            int len;
            NSMutableData *output = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
            while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                if (len > 0) {
                    [output appendBytes: (const void *)buffer length:len];
                }
            }
```

But I am not sure how to force the app to only read one JSON from the server at a time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each JSON block is sent on a single line, and the lines are separated by a newline
character, you can do the following:

- Add a property (or instance variable) `NSMutableData *collectedData` to your class.
- In the `case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:` initialize the collected data:

  ```
  collectedData = [NSMutableData data];
  ```
- In the `case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:`, append all received data to the
  collected data. Then check if there is a newline character. In that case, extract the
  line (from the beginning until the newline character) into a separate `NSData` object
  and remove it from the collected data. This could look like the following (untested) code:

  ```
  NSData *nl = [@"\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  uint8_t buffer[1024];
  int len;
  while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
      len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
      [collectedData appendBytes: (const void *)buffer length:len];
  }
  NSRange nlRange =[collectedData rangeOfData:nl options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [collectedData length])];
  while (nlRange.location != NSNotFound) {
      // Extract data from the beginning up to (but not including) the newline character:
      NSData *jsonData = [collectedData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, nlRange.location)];
      // Remove data from the beginning up to and including the newline character:
      [collectedData replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, nlRange.location + nlRange.length) withBytes:NULL length:0];

      // Process jsonData ...
      NSError *error;
      NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
      // ...

      // Check for another newline character:
      nlRange =[collectedData rangeOfData:nl options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [collectedData length])];
  }
  ```

Comment: I added the `collectedData` to my .h like so: `NSMutableData *collectedData;` is that what you ment?

Comment: @user3082584: Yes. (The "modern" way would be to define a "property", but that is a different topic and unrelated to your problem.)